# is the following solutions' time complexity O(N)?

Tags: python, algorithm, time, big-o, complexity-theory

I tried to calculate the time complexity for the function "twoSum" and wrote the cost of each line and how many times it's executed. Finally, I made two vectors: one for the costs and another for frequencies, then calculated the inner product of them. I got the following: `(n + n + nlogn + n + n + nlogn + n + n + n + n) = 9n + 2logn >> 9n` dominates so the time complexity is `O(n)`. Please correct me if I am wrong!

```
class Solution(object):

    def binarySearch(self,arr, l, r, x): 
    if r >= l: 
        mid = l + (r - l)/2
        if arr[mid] == x: return mid 
        elif arr[mid] > x:return self.binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x)  
        else: return self.binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x) 
    else:return -1

    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    temp = [i for i in nums] # o(n) 1 time
    nums = list(set(nums)) # o(n) 1 time
    nums.sort() # o(nlogn) 1 time
    for i in range(len(nums)): # o(n) 1 time 
        s = target - nums[i] #  o(1) n times 
        idx_binary = self.binarySearch(nums, 0, len(nums)-1, s) # o(logn) > n times 
        if idx_binary > -1: # o(1) n times 
                idx = temp.index(s, temp.index(nums[i])+1) # o(n) > 1 time
                return [temp.index(nums[i]), idx] # o(n) > 1 time
            else:
                return [temp.index(nums[i]), temp.index(s)] # o(n) > 1 time
```

Comment: the row which  runs "o(logn) > n times" has O(nlogn) time complexity if I understand correctly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your simplification has a mistake, it should be 9n + 2**n**logn where nlogn dominates, so the answer is O(nlogn)